# Mocha - path.join undefined - node.js

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, undefined

I'm absolutely banging my head against a wall whilst running a simple mocha test.

The test is falling over on the path. join line because the path is undefined - however as you'll see from the script it is already required further up the script.

I'm running my mocha test via VSCode - do I need to extend my launch config at all?

```
const assert = require('chai').assert

const path = require('path')

//load config
const config = require('../config/config.json');
const defaultConfig = config.development;


describe('Import', function() {
    describe('check import entries exist', function(path) {

        var test = path.join(defaultConfig.uploadDir, 'test')

        assert.equal('C:\upload\test',test)

    });


});
```

Launch config looks like:

```
{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Mocha All",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
            "args": [
                "--timeout",
                "999999",
                "--colors",
                "${workspaceFolder}/tests/**.js"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Mocha Current File",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
            "args": [
                "--timeout",
                "999999",
                "--colors",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
```

Comment: You require `path` at the top but also have `path` as the parameter name in your test function. `describe('check import entries exist', function(path) {...` should be `describe('check import entries exist', function() {...`